# Group by with Count on very large table

Tags: mysql, count, out-of-memory, unique

I have a very large table, 25+ Million records.

I need to create a new table from it where three fields are unique.

I tried

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3, Count(*) FROM `Table`  group by Field1,Field2,Field3 having Count(*)>1
```

I get err- out of memory from Mysql

Is there a more efficient way of finding all the unique records with those fields with a count > 1 so I can work with them further (create a new table, etc)?

Comment: If you need the count, you'll have to use `group by`.

Comment: do you have an id column auto_inc ? Also how many rows

Comment: Depending on the data types and values stored in Field1, Field2, and Field3; you could use carefully constructed conditions in a `WHERE` clause to separate the data into more manageable distinct "chunks", and run several such queries to get the whole. (Example: If Field1 is a numeric type with roughly evenly distributed values, you could query based on subranges of the values spanned; if it is a string type you could perhaps separate the data based on the first character or two.)

Comment: *depending* on the data values too, you can synthesize a field(n) value down to an int

Comment: @drew I have an ID column with autoinc, and each of the fields called has an index. About 25 columns and 25 million rows.

Comment: now it's time to answer uu's question. Also, I don't understand what `and each of the fields called has an index` means

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I figured out a way to work with count=1 on the back end of this, how could i make this much faster then?

Comment: post your table schema please. how fast is the same query with no count?

Comment: Have you ONE index with all three fields in the sam order  Field1,Field2,Field3 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the count, then the following may produce what you want:

```
select field1, field2, field3
form table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.field1 = t.field1 and t2.field2 = t.field2 and
                    t2.field3 = t.field3 and t2.id > t.id
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.field1 = t.field1 and t2.field2 = t.field2 and
                        t2.field3 = t.field3 and t2.id < t2.id
                 );
```

The first clause guarantees that more than one row exists.  The second only returns the minimum id for the combination.

I do realize that for this to finish in finite time, you need an index on the three fields:

```
create index idx_table_field1_field2_field3 on table(field1, field2, field3)
```

If the `group by` fails, then this may also fail.  But, if it succeeds, then this method might actually be pretty fast -- assuming the index can fit into memory.

Comment: @Gordan the index on the three fields together did the trick even using my original query. I thought having an index ON each field was enough but clearly it was required on the group. Thanks!

Comment: @user3649739 . . . Interesting.  It can be challenging to get MySQL to use an index for aggregation, but this is clearly a case where that works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution without changing the server memory configuration is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ttt AS 
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3, Count(*) AS counter
FROM `Table`  group by Field1,Field2,Field3;
```

This might prevent out of memory since the having clause does not need to be evaluated. Then after that run a query again the table **ttt** for the **counter>1**.

You will have to test required to see if it works. It will be slow (especially the second query since there is no index it can use on the temporary table and first creating an index has no use when you just run that where statement).